# Formatting generic page content with white-space:pre-wrap - any reason not to?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Lets say, that I have a web-page with this element as the main content:

```
<div id="maincontent">
  <h2>Sub-header</h2>
  <p>Some stuff.</p>
  <p>More stuff.</p>
  <p>Even more stuff.</p>
  <p>
    <span class="bold">Contact:</span><br>
    Guy With Name<br>
    09-009 990<br>
    <a href="mailto:guy.with.name@atkkierratys.com">email</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Is there a reason to NOT to do it in a way described below?

```
<div id="maincontent" style="white-space:pre-wrap">
<h2>Sub-header</h2>

Some stuff.

More stuff.

Even more stuff.

<span class="bold">Contact:</span>
Guy With Name
09-009 990
<a href="mailto:guy.with.name@atkkierratys.com">email</a>
</div>
```

On the target site, the content is going to be quite simplified in appearance, and there very likely wont be any fancy UI-tricks or JS tools which would require DOM-structure in the main content. Content will be edited with notepad-level apps (unless there's site-builder-apps that can deal shtml, combined with situation where I wouldn't be available for any reason). One reason why I would be doing this, would be a lot more easy editing for less HTML-savvy people, to make the site as little relied on me as possible (the whole association is based on volunteering).

As a side note: The pages were created and edited with WYSIWYG-editor before I stepped in. By replacing the code with hand written, the document sizes halved.

Comment: When you take out the tags like that, you're stripping away anything that would give clues as to the meaning of the content.  Is it not possible to get some sort of markdown/bbcode parser to fix up the content before it is served to the user?

Comment: Could you elaborate about "clues as to the meaning of the content"? Basically, I could build them simple CMS and tell them to learn how to make styled forum posts. When I have the time, maybe I will, who knows? But for now, I'd be curious to know if there's any reason for not cutting out all the html-tags that are there basically only for assisting with displaying the information in a certain way.

Comment: Aside from `div` and `span`, each tag has semantic meaning behind it.  Most browsers don't add a lot of default styling, but screen reader would express the content differently depending on what kind of tag is used (is it a list?  are they paragraphs?).  As a general rule of thumb, the content should make sense without any styling at all.

Comment: There's some point indeed. Yet, is there more points to consider?

Answer (score 0):

If you want some thing like that then give text with in `<pre></pre>`

Comment: I recently learned that I had misunderstood how <pre></pre> works (or it's behavior has changed during years). It definitely doesn't prevent usage of html inside itself, as I previously thought. How `pre` affects semantics? How search engines, or screen readers behave with it? (I deleted my earlier comment to prevent misinforming)